# How access multiples objects in a list

Tags: elm

I have this code in Elm-lang:

```
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Html exposing (..)


json =  -- List that contains and will have many users
 """
 [{\"ssn\":\"111.111.111-11\",\"name\":\"People Silva\",\"email\":\"people@eat.com\"}, {\"ssn\":\"000.000.000-00\",\"name\":\"Pet Silva\",\"email\":\"pet@eat.com\"}]
 """

type alias User =
  { name : String
  , email: String
  , ssn: String
  }


userDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder User
userDecoder =
  Json.Decode.map3 User
    (field "name" string)
    (field "email" string)
    (field "ssn" string)


userListDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder (List User)
userListDecoder =
  Json.Decode.list userDecoder


main =
  let
    decoded = (decodeString userListDecoder json)
  in
    case decoded of
      Ok u ->
        span [] [text (toString u)]

      Err e ->
        span [] [text (toString e)]
```

This code work very well, and output this(how expected):

```
[{ name = "People Silva", email = "people@eat.com", ssn = "111.111.111-11" },{ name = "Pet Silva", email = "pet@eat.com", ssn = "000.000.000-00" }]
```

And here begins my doubt, how get list of all users in list?(And also as a bonus, get the number of users in the list)

```
-- already tried, unsuccessfully
u[0].name
u[1].name
```

Comment: do you mean you want a list of all the users' names only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users are in a `List User` value, so you can use the [functions from the `List` package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/List) to access them.

If you want to get a list of user names from a list of users, you can call `List.map .name users`.

If you want to write the user names in their own divs, you can write it like this:

```
showUser : User -> Html msg
showUser user =
    div [] [ text user.name ]
```

and call it from `main` like this:

```
main =
  let
    decoded = (decodeString userListDecoder json)
  in
    case decoded of
      Ok users ->
        div [] (List.map showUser users)

      Err e ->
        span [] [text (toString e)]
```

Obtaining the length of a list is just a matter of using the [`List.length`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/List#length) function: `List.length users`

Comment: Thank you for the speed, simplicity and efficiency.